# Sqlite database crash

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Is there a way to prevent the sqlite db to crash? I have a listview with items in it. When you click on a button al items are saved in a db. But when there are a lot of products in the list and you click verry fast on the save button the application freezes. And when I check my database afterwards all the items are saved multiple times.

Someone knows the answer?

Code:
With isProdAlreadyFavorite I check if the db already got an entry with the id...
When you click on the button he executes this function..

```
public void addFavProducten(ArrayList<Product> producten) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        for (Product product : producten) {
            if (!isProdAlreadyFavorite(product.getProductid())) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(Constanten.FAV_PROD_COLUMN_PRODUCTID,
                        product.getProductid());
                db.insert(Constanten.TABLE_FAVPROD, null, cv);
            }
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        db.endTransaction();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just disable the 'Save' button as soon as the user clicks it, save the data and then enable the button. Also you need to change your DB 'save' code to prevent things being saved multiple times.

Comment: What crash?  Sounds like the database is working perfectly.

Comment: Don't forget to use transactions and some sort of flag to note if there is a new item or an item being updated.

Comment: Sounds like a re-entrancy problem or a loop somewhere in the ui. No sign of sqlite problem and no sign of crash (freeze isn't).

Comment: At first I didn't use a transaction. Now I do and the view doesn't freeze. But he still enters duplicates..